# what is the definition of "two parallel copies of a surface S"

Tags: general-topology, surfaces

As indicated in the title,

suppose $S$ is a surface with genus $g$, then

what is the definition of "two parallel copies of S"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $S$ is embedded in an orientable manifold, then there is a well-defined normal direction. So you can push off a copy of $S$ along this normal direction to get two parallel copies. It is the same as embedding $S\times [0,1]$ in the ambient manifold and considering the restriction $S\times\{0,1\}$.

Comment: thanks, so it is kind of disjoint union, the resulting surface has genus 2g?

Comment: The resulting surface is disconnected. Normally genus is only defined for connected surfaces. But yes, it is a particular kind of disjoint union.